# Can not CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql

I am working library project. I want to create a database and table, but I do not know why my codes do not work. I check all create table syntax  no errors.
Could you teach me how to fix them?

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS LIBRARYS;
CREATE DATABASE LIBRARYS;
USE LIBRARYS; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BOOK;

CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
 title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 author VARCHAR(30),
 BookId INT auto_increment,
 ISBN INT,
 Edition VARCHAR(50),
 YearBought INT,
 Category VARCHAR (30),
 LibraryBranchID INT auto_increment,

 PRIMARY KEY(BookId),
 FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(BranchName)
 );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person;
CREATE TABLE Person
(PersonId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 uNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 age INT,
 UserType VARCHAR (30),
 PreferredBranch INT,
 updatedOn timestamp not null on update current_timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY ( PreferredBranch) references LibraryBranch(LibraryBranchID)
) ;
ALTER table Person AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOAN;
CREATE TABLE LOAN
(LoanId INT auto_increment,
 Pid INT,
 Bid INT,
 loanDate DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 overdue BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
 PRIMARY KEY(LoanId),
 FOREIGN KEY (Pid) references Person (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY (Bid) references Book(BookId) 
) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LibraryBranch ;
CREATE TABLE LibraryBranch
(uID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 LibraryBranchID INT auto_increment,
 BranchName INT,
 updatedOn timestamp not null on update current_timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (LibraryBranchID)
) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Rating;
CREATE TABLE Rating
(RatingId INT ,
 RatingDate INT,
 BookId INT,
 PersonId INT,
 Stars BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
 PRIMARY KEY(RatingId),
 FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) references Person (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY (BookId) references BOOK(BookId) 
) ;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' INTO TABLE BOOK;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' INTO TABLE Person;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' INTO TABLE LOAN;
```

Here I got those results

```
1 row(s) affected

0 row(s) affected

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1051 Unknown table 'librarys.book'

Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: `LibraryBranch` has two `auto_increment` fields.  You can't do that (just like the error says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE LibraryBranch` should be before your call `FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(BranchName)`

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
 ...
 BookId INT auto_increment,
 ... 
 LibraryBranchID INT auto_increment,
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY(BookId),
 FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(BranchName)
 );
```

and if `FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(BranchName)` this `LibraryBranchID` can't be **auto_increment**

`FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(BranchName)` wrong field **BranchName** called should be **LibraryBranchID**:

```
 FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(LibraryBranchID)
```

and there is no need to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` each table since you just created the database

**UPDATE**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86bb96

```
CREATE TABLE LibraryBranch
(uID INT,
 LibraryBranchID INT auto_increment,
 BranchName INT,
 updatedOn timestamp not null on update current_timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (LibraryBranchID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
 title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 author VARCHAR(30),
 BookId INT auto_increment,
 ISBN INT,
 Edition VARCHAR(50),
 YearBought INT,
 Category VARCHAR (30),
 LibraryBranchID INT ,
 PRIMARY KEY(BookId),
 FOREIGN KEY ( LibraryBranchID) references LibraryBranch(LibraryBranchID)
 );

CREATE TABLE Person
(PersonId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 uNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 age INT,
 UserType VARCHAR (30),
 PreferredBranch INT,
 updatedOn timestamp not null on update current_timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY ( PreferredBranch) references LibraryBranch(LibraryBranchID)
) ;
ALTER table Person AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;

CREATE TABLE LOAN
(LoanId INT auto_increment,
 Pid INT,
 Bid INT,
 loanDate DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 overdue BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
 PRIMARY KEY(LoanId),
 FOREIGN KEY (Pid) references Person (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY (Bid) references Book(BookId) 
) ;

CREATE TABLE Rating
(RatingId INT ,
 RatingDate INT,
 BookId INT,
 PersonId INT,
 Stars BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
 PRIMARY KEY(RatingId),
 FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) references Person (PersonId),
 FOREIGN KEY (BookId) references BOOK(BookId) 
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
CREATE TABLE LibraryBranch
(uID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 LibraryBranchID INT auto_increment,
 BranchName INT,
 updatedOn timestamp not null on update current_timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (LibraryBranchID)
) ;
```

You made `uID` an auto column, but `LibraryBranchID` is the PK.

Comment: Repost your current code in your question.  You must have done something wrong in attempting to delete uID.

Comment: I removed all foreign key and auto_increment that works, but I have to add foreign key to reference some. How can I do?

Comment: You can add foreign keys that reference the primary key of another table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two auto_increment fields in mysql innodb tables.
You can use trigger for second field if you want it to auto increment.

Comment: I delete all others auto_increment, and I left one on the person table. Errors still there as Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: re send the schema you are using. from the message it appears you are erroneously creating the table with foreign key constraint